# Pay Eth to ChainLink

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, chainlink

I want to pay the chain link's cost automatically with  Eth tokens instead of link tokens because I have eth tokens in my smart contract, is this possible?
I need everything to be automated and if I pay link tokens to chain link it can be a single point of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chainlink services currently require payment with LINK tokens exclusively. Users must acquire LINK tokens from supported exchanges to pay for oracle requests and data retrieval within the Chainlink ecosystem.

However, the Chainlink team is actively working on an improved payment model to support an expanded monetization approach. This initiative aims to simplify payment for dApps and developers using Chainlink services, allowing payments in other assets, including native tokens, at a higher rate than LINK payments. These alternative asset payments can be converted into LINK, increasing overall LINK consumption and facilitating the payment process.

Blog: https://blog.chain.link/the-chainlink-network-in-2023/